# Help needed on graphing on the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> Graph $f(x) = \csc x$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Any advice on how to graph would be appreciated.

Comment: Break the interval into four pieces, each of lenth $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Use the fact that $\csc{x}=\frac{1}{\sin{x}}$ and ask yourself what happens as you go from one end of each of the pieces to the other end.

Comment: Make a lightly pencilled graph of $\sin x$. For example $\sin x$ grows from $0$ to $1$ on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$. So near $0$, $csc x$ is huge positive, and decreases to $1$ at $x=\pi/2$. Then by the symmetry of $\sin x$ about $\pi/2$, $\csc x$ grows steadily until it reaches huge positive values as we get near to $\pi$. And so on.

Comment: I've edited out the image because its scale and size made it badly distorted and caused a lot of unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: This might be to much to ask but could I see a visual representation of your answer perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of question where it helps to have a good understanding of the graph of $g(x) = \sin x$, and it helps to recall the fact that $f(x) = \csc x = \frac 1{\sin x}$.

Knowing that $\,-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1\,$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ helps you find the "range" of the function $f(x) = \csc x = \dfrac 1{\sin x}$.

Plot $f(\pi/2) = \dfrac{1}{\sin(\pi/2)} = \dfrac 11 = 1.\;$ Plot $\;f(3\pi/2) = \dfrac{1}{\sin(3\pi/2)} = \dfrac{1}{-1} = -1.$

Draw the vertical lines $\,x = 0,\; x = \pi,\; x = 2\pi.\;$ The graph of $f(x)$ will never intersect any of those vertical lines. The lines I've listed are called vertical *asymptotes*. $\csc x = \dfrac 1{\sin x}$ is *not defined* at $x = 0, x = \pi...$ nor at any integer multiple of $\pi$. Why not?

Calculate the values $f(x)$ when $x$ takes on values *between* the first two points plotted and the vertical lines on each side of those you've drawn, and plot some of the corresponding ordered pairs $(x, f(x))$, when $x \in (0, 2\pi), \;x\neq \pi$.

For more intuition, compare the graphs of $\sin x$ and $\csc x = \dfrac 1{\sin x},\,$ below, and compare your "sketch-in-progress" of $f(x) = \csc x = \dfrac 1{\sin x}$.

[image]

Comment: Graphs speak to me always. Life without them is like breakfast without milk. :+)

Comment: @amWhy: I agree with Babak and is comment made me hungry for breakfast! :-) +1